# On key press search in asp.net vb.net in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a search that display all matches information on key pressed.
I tell you now I'm not a professional 
still learning

I have arrived at this point

```
Private Sub BindGrid(SearchTerm As String)
    Using conss As New SqlConnection(_start)

    Dim query As String = "SELECT Item.Name, Item.Quantity, Item.Price, Item.Condition ``FROM Item INNER JOIN Seller ON Item.SellerID = Seller.SellerID INNER JOIN Member ON Seller.MemberID = Member.MemberID WHERE (Item.Status = 'Available') or (Item.Status = 'Quantity') ORDER By NEWID() "
        Dim mycommand2 As New SqlCommand(query, conss)

        Dim category As SqlDataReader
        category = mycommand2.ExecuteReader()


        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name"))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Quantity"))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Price"))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Condition"))

        For i As Integer = 1 To 12
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            dr("col1") = i
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
        '-- use DefaultView to filter the records
        Dim dw As DataView = dt.DefaultView
        dw.RowFilter = "Col1 like '%" + txtSearch.Text.Trim() + "%'"
        Repeater1.DataSource = dw
        Repeater1.DataBind()

    End Using


       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

         <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").keypress(function () {
            //-- trigger click event of dummy button
            //-- we will write bind grid function on this click event on server side
            $("#<%=btnDummy.ClientID%>").click();
        });
    });
        </script>
     </head>
        <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDummy" runat="server" Text="testbutton" style="display:none" OnClick="btnDummy_Click" />
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

I don't know how to bind my sql to my repeater, i want the search to be done on the name column on key press in the textbox can someone help me to modify my code please

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb) to learn how to bind your repeater to your sql, for your search function you should see an example of the the FilterRepeater Class [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2008/09/25/tweaking-the-filter-repeater.aspx).

Comment: Those are some helpful links, but if you can summarize them in addition to providing the link, it will assist users who cannot follow the link (if it goes offline in the future, or the linked page is blocked by a firewall for them).  See the [How to Answer Help Center post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).